# using inputHidden field to pass value to constructor and control date values

Tags: apex

I have a page which displays user records in a table. I would then like like to add navigation buttons which will render table when clicked. These buttons will be based on date. i.e. initially on page load, it displays records based on todays date. by clicking the previous button, it should display records from yesterday, etc. The main task here is that I am trying to do most of the logic on server side and minimize calls to the constructor each time the button is clicked.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="photoBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputText>
                <i class="fa  fa-arrow-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" onclick="setVar('{!formatDate}'); return false;"></i>
                <apex:commandLink value="{!formatDate}" id="theCommandLink"/>
                <apex:inputHidden value="{!formatDate}" id="dateHiddenField"/>
                <i class="fa  fa-arrow-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relevantContacts}" var="relatedCon" cellpadding="1" border="1" id="relevantContacts" rendered="{!relevantContacts.size > 0}">
            <apex:column headerValue="Requested Appointments" value="{!relatedCon.Photographer__r.Name}"/>
            <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="9">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relatedCon}" var="c" id="contactTable">
                    <apex:column id="theHiddenInput1" headerValue="6 AM" styleClass="{!IF(contains(c.Time_Slot__c, '6:00 AM - 8:00 AM'), 'greenHighlight', 'normalHighlight')}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:actionFunction name="passStringToController" action="{!myMethod}" rerender="photoBlock"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Javascript:

```
        window.setVar = function(param){
        console.log(param);
        var day = param.split('-')[0];
        var month = param.split('-')[1];
        var year = param.split('-')[2];
        var d = Date.parse(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
        $([id$='dateHiddenField']).val(d);
        passStringToController();
    }
```

Constructor:

```
public with sharing class APP_CalendarAppCTRL {

public String appointmentTime1 { get; set; }
public String appointmentTime2 { get; set; }
public String checkAvailability2 { get; set; }
public List<APP_Appointment__c> relevantContacts {get; set;}
public String formatDate { get; set; }

public APP_CalendarAppCTRL() {
    formatDate = formatDateFunc();
    relevantContacts = getAllPhotographerUsers();
    System.debug('relevantContacts : ' + relevantContacts);
}

public static String formatDateFunc() {
    return Date.today().day() + '-' + Date.today().month() + '-' + Date.today().year();
}

public PageReference myMethod(){
    System.debug('formatDate: ' + formatDate);
    return null;
}

public static List<APP_Appointment__c> getAllPhotographerUsers(){
    return [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, Time_Slot__c, Photographer__c, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Contact__c, Photographer__r.Name, Photographer__r.Id, Status__c, Date__c FROM APP_Appointment__c];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call the constructor once per initial page load. It's not called each time there is already a view state present. So, your initial problem is that you need to set relevantContacts in myMethod:

```
public void myMethod(){
    relevantContacts = getAllPhotographerUsers();
}
```

I would suggest that you ditch the JavaScript and just calculate the new date in Apex Code, because it's a lot easier in Apex:

```
public Date viewDate { get; set; }
public APP_CalenderAppCtrl() {
    viewDate = Date.today();
    myMethod();
}
public void prevDate() {
    viewDate = viewDate.addDays(-1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. However, my issue now is that i would also want to change the records using the viewDate. So in my modified soql, it would be something like WHERE Date__c = viewDate. viewDate is not exposed because it isn't static. How can I work round this?

Comment: @saint There's no reason for your method to be static. Static methods are typically for utility methods stored in a separate class, like most trigger handler frameworks.